# New magnitude frequency after apply highpass butterworth filter

Tags: highpass-filter

I want to use high pass filter to filter frequency less than 100Hz. I use this code in python.

```
def butter_highpass(lowcut, fs, order=9):
nyq = 0.5 * fs
low = lowcut / nyq
b, a = butter(order, low, btype='high', analog = False)
return b, a

def butter_highpass_filter(data, lowcut,  fs, order=9):
b, a = butter_highpass(lowcut, fs, order=order)
y = lfilter(b, a, data)
return y
```

My signal before filter (use plt.magnitude_spectrum function):
[image]

and my signal after filter:

[image]

It show that some new frequency appear(from 200Hz -> 2000Hz). and I don't know why?. Can anyone explain why?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If there was nothing wrong with your filtering, the “new” frequencies were always there, but  too small to see on the scale of your first plot.

If you had plotted the logarithm of magnitude instead of linear magnitude, the spectral components would have been more obvious.

To summarize, the “new” frequencies probably aren’t new, just too small to see given the scale of the first plot.